# Time Series pattern recognition and classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, time-series, feature-extraction, anomaly-detection

I have some labeled sensor data.

Now, I would like to know how to extract features from time series using DFT, DWT, and HAAR transforms.

I know that the transformations above transform a signal to frequency or time frequency domain, but how can I get average frequency for this non stationary signal?

Comment: Have you been able to transform your data? Or do you basically ask how to transform it?

Comment: I tried to edit your post but in the last sentence I got stuck! I changed "the" to "but" but I think it's still unclear what you want.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to find an average frequency. What is your higher-level question you want to answer? What kind of sensor is it for which you have data? What is your sampling rate?

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand what you mean by "average frequency". But this may help to think about it.

- You can calculate the power spectrum of the signal using DFT.
- From the power spectrum, you will be able to get the average power of all the frequencies.
- Use this value of average power to map the frequency which it closely corresponds to.

This will give a sort of the average frequency you are looking for from the average value of power.